# Not Implemented for this I/O Control Type

Tags: labview, data-acquisition

When I right-click on the "DAQ Assistant" in my VI and select "Generate NI-DAQmx Code", I get the error:

```
Not implemented for this I/O control type.
```

I am using an NI-9237. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you show how did you configure DAQmx task in DAQ Assistant?

Comment: What kind of task/measurement are you doing?

Answer (score 0):

Driver on cRIO did not match driver on local host (FYI, I was compiling on a RT cRIO).